# Python Flask MySQL: How to persistently store connection pool object?

Tags: python, flask, mysql-connector, multi-database-connections

After a long search, I could not find an answer to my question and if what I desire is even possible. My question concerns a MySQL connection implementation for a Flask API. What I desire to implement is as follows:

1. When the Flask app is started, a `create_db_connection` method is called, which created a number of mysql connections in a pooling object.
2. For each incoming request, a `get_connection` method is called, to get one connection from the poule
3. And of course when the request is ended, a method `close_connection` is called to close the connection and mark it available in the pool.

The problem I'm having concerns persistently storing the connection pool such that it can be re-used for each request.

create_db_connection method:

```
def create_db_connection():
    print("-----INITIALISING-----")
    db_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name = "BestLiar_Public_API",
                                                        pool_size = 10,
                                                        autocommit = True,
                                                        pool_reset_session = True,
                                                        user = 'user',
                                                        password = 'pass',
                                                        host = 'hostel',
                                                        database =' db')
    print("-----DB POOL INITIALISED-----")
    
    // SOLUTION TO PERSISTENTLY SAVE db_pool OBJECT
```

get_connection method:

```
def __enter__(self):
    try:

        // SOLUTION TO FETCH THE db_pool OBJECT > NAMED AS db_pool IN LINE BELOW

        self.con = db_pool.get_connection()
        self.cur = self.con.cursor(dictionary=True)
        if self.con.is_connected():
            return {'cur': self.cur, 'con': self.con}
        else:
            raise NoConnectionError("No database connection", "Pool connection not connected")
    except mysql.connector.PoolError:
        raise SystemOverload("Too many requests, could not process","No pool connection available")
    except:
        raise NoConnectionError("No database connection", "Unknown reason")
```

close_connection method:

```
def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    if self.con: 
        self.cur.close()
        self.con.close()
```

I have tried storing the db_pool object as a global variable (undesirable) and have tried the flask global object (only works for one request).
Anyone who has the key to the solution?

Comment: Can you distinguish why/how 'persistently storing' and a 'global variable' are different?

Comment: If you look at it that way, you are right since it is conceptually the same thing, but global variables do not work in some environments, which is why I am looking into alternatives. I want the database connection pool to live the entire span of the Flask session, which cannot be guaranteed with a global variable.